# Cannot mount volume in swarm mode

Tags: php, docker, containers, swarm

I have an image of php7.2 which is now working in production mode. When I tried to create a service of the current image , I got `"cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4726faf1f3b385e805dec93e0e411acf322ca5ba6d5fd24666c24cb2f85ef810/merged/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini"`

I have tried by removing local.ini from the stack , but no change happened.
Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try simply removing this file from the host you're running your image on?  I.e. `sudo rm -f /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4726faf1f3b385e805dec93e0e411acf322ca5ba6d5fd24666c24cb2f85ef810/merged/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini`

Comment: Thanks for your comment , but I cannot remove that volume because it is being used by other containers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, as I could not remove the volume because it was being used by the other containers , I mounted that volume into my new swarm containers using `swarm stack deploy` command and `docker compose`.